# How does Rails handle database errors when creating multiple records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know I could walk through the framework to get this answer myself but I'm hoping someone could save me the time.

The `Model.create` method lets me create an array of new objects:

```
# Create an Array of new objects
User.create([{ :first_name => 'Jamie' }, { :first_name => 'Jeremy' }])
```

It seems that behind the scene Rails simply calls `create` on each of these objects one at a time. I am just wondering, if any of the `create` calls fail due to a database issue, will Rails rollback all of the changes made by the previous calls or is this something I would have to handle myself?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class

Comment: If you look at  create you will see that it checks to see if you have passed in an array in which case it calls itself on each element in the array. I'm just concerned with what would happen if any of those create calls fail. I'm trying to decide the best way to implement error handling to insure there are no unnecessary duplication of data in the database(which would happen if a database exception is raised and the user re-posts because of it).

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but related - https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/

Answer (score 0):

Normally, by default `rails` assumes you have a table called `users` which is related to `User` model,

and most importantly `rails` assumes, it has a auto increment primary key called `id`, so when it create a record, `rails` will insert everything expect the `id` field.

So when you create multiple record, it will simply create a unique key for each record.

however you could override this defaults :)